# Why does my left join perform as an inner join

Tags: mysql, wordpress, join

I want to perform a left join on the wordpress tables `wp_posts` and `wp_postmeta`.

Starting with a simple select from the `wp_posts` table

```
 select ID from wp_posts
```

this is the output:

```
'1'
'2'
'14'
'15'
'16'
'17'
...
```

It should be doing my left join query

```
select a.ID from wp_posts a
left JOIN wp_postmeta b on  b.post_id = a.ID
```

This is the output:

```
 '1'
 '1'
 '1'
 '2'
 '2'
 '2'
 '14'
 '14'
 '14'
 ...
```

which is incorrect, my left join is not acting like a left join here.

What can be the issue with my simple left join ?

Comment: LEFT JOIN *IS* an OUTER JOIN !! The OUTER keyword is optional !?!?!

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: My guess is that there are 3 records in post_meta with post_id is 1

Comment: Gervs, thats true, but a left join should only take all elements from the left collection ?

Answer (score 0):

It is working as it should. I can't think of a reason a LEFT JOIN would ever return less rows than an otherwise identical INNER JOIN; probably the simplest way to illustrate this is to add fields from wp_postmeta to your SELECTed fields and see the results. 
Now, if you wanted all ID values from wp_posts, you could do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.ID 
FROM wp_posts a 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta b ON b.post_id = a.ID
;
```

But it wouldn't make a whole lot of sense why you wouldn't just use your original (non-joining) query.